# java, DbUnit, FlatXmlDataSetBuilder

Tags: java, база-данных, юнит-тесты

времени суток! Ситуация, я пишу тест с обращением к базе данных (postegreSQL), использую DbUnit для эмуляции базы данных, данные для базы данных содержаться в xml. Есть переопределенный метод

```
@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
    return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(loadFile("dao/group/dataSet.xml"));
}
```

который собственно и подгружает данные в базу данных. И вот вопрос, существует ли какой либо метод, загрузить сначала один xml (dao/group/dataSet.xml), а затем добавить еще один (или несколько xml)? На данный момент в исходном xml содержится данные для нескольких таблиц, а есть потребность, подгружать по мере необходимости данные, для каждой таблицы в отдельным xml. Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Есть [такой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223836/6752984) , правда не проверял работоспособность.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!